# CodeIgniter - unlimited parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am currently using CodeIgniter.

I am trying to write a function that can take an unlimited number of paramaters.

So in the controller it will be something like

```
function test($name, $others){
    foreach($others){
       //do something
    }
}
```

and I could call it like

```
example.com/control/test/some name/param1/param2/param3/param4/param5...
```

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get an associated array of URI segments with the `uri_to_assoc` function in the [URI class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html). So in your controller, you might do something like this:

```
function test($name){
    $uri_seg = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);

    foreach($uri_seg as $para){
        // Do something with each of the URI segments passed in here after $name
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers,

Is there one to get a non-assoc array?

So simply an array of `array('param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4', 'param5');` ?

Comment: @Haiwood I think the `segment_array()` function should do that

Comment: why not just use php's native [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Answer (score 7):

you could also do it like this:

```
function foo($params=array())
{
    $params=func_get_args();
    //print_r($params);
}
```

so any url like:

`site.com/controller/foo/param1/param2/param3/param4`

would create an array of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need an unlimited (variable) number of arguments, but you may want to consider why you need them.

You can use alternative URI semantics for certain types of arguments. Often the URI design is the path to a thing in a system. Unlimited parameters may not refer to the resource, but rather describe its attributes. Tags are a good example of this.

```
/chicken/red+tall+fat
```

Tags implement easily in CodeIgniter with a single parameter.

If the parameters refer to a node, you can consider a similar approach:

```
/hen-house.bunk4.topshelf/chicken
```

Or, if the hierarchy is important as a path, you can use the `func_get_args()` solution above.

Comment: an example: your application has a list (a list of houses for sale), and the html UI allows the user to `filter` the list with keywords (eg. "garage,2bedrooms,balcony,central air,fireplace") ... if you can assign these filter words to a url, then you could easily send a link to the filtered list (`www.example.com/garage/2bedrooms/balcony/central air/fireplace`)