# Passing many argument to controller function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a controller named as Tag which is related to handling posts related to certain tags as wish by viewer

I want to make URL look like this

```
http://www.mydomain/tag/xxx/xxx
```

where the viewer can filter the post via using as many tags as they like

e.g

```
http://www.mydomain/tag/XXX/XXX/.../..../...
```

I have tried this via using regular expression in routes.php

```
$route['tag\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]']='tag/index';
```

and filtering the URL in index method of Tag controller but it didn't work for more than 1 tag. I want the user can pass as many tags as they wish. The methods said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237220/codeigniter-unlimited-parameters) also didn't work.Is there any way to do this for index method?

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this way, Hacker might be hack your application and harm valuable data.
It will make your site vulnerable.

so,I think you should go for another way...

```
/controller/method/red+tall+fat
```

Comment: Since I'm using this for post managing in blogging site and the tags passed via URL will be escaped via CodeIgniter during database query. Also if there is nothing related to that tag user will see not found message. I don't think it will be valuable